# Cannot keep user session alive on protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, protractor

I am using Protractor for e2e testing on my Application.

**STORY:** For a specific use case I need to make sure the number of items on a table matches the API response. I read that I can use the 'request' to make http calls and retrieve the information. I need to be an authenticated user in my browser session to retrieve the information.

**PROBLEM:** After sucessfully logging in, I try to fetch the items list, but get a 401 response ('no user session available').

**Some material:**

```
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');
app.createSession = function() {
    var formData = querystring.stringify({
        email: browser.params.user.admin.email,
        password: browser.params.user.admin.password
    });

    request({
        url: "https://MY_API_DOMAIN/auth",
        method : 'POST',
        headers: [
        {
        name: 'Accept',
        value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        ],
        body: formData
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log('FIRST:', body); //returning 200 ALL FINE
        request({
            url: "https://MY_API_DOMAIN/api/v1/auth",
            method : 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: [{
                  name: 'Accept',
                  value: 'application/json'
            }]
        }, function(err, response, body) {
            console.log('SECOND:', body); //returning 401
        });
    });
};
```

If you need more info please let me know. When I simulate a a login on my HTML with Selenium, all works fine and the items are being fetched. The problem is when processing the HTTP request inside my helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Protractor promises and controlFlow in order to turn async calls into sequential execution and force framework to wait until all promises are resolved and the flow is complete. In order to achieve this all async function will have to return a promise that will be solved later.

The code will become:

```js
it ("expect to call all functions", function() {
  createSession = function() {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    var formData = querystring.stringify({
        email: browser.params.user.admin.email,
        password: browser.params.user.admin.password
    });

    request({
        url: "https://MY_API_DOMAIN/auth",
        method : 'POST',
        headers: [
        {
        name: 'Accept',
        value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        ],
        body: formData
    }, function(err, response, body1) {
        
        console.log('FIRST:', body1); //returning 200 ALL FINE
        request({
            url: "https://MY_API_DOMAIN/api/v1/auth",
            method : 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: [{
                  name: 'Accept',
                  value: 'application/json'
            }]
        }, function(err, response, body2) {
            defer.fulfill({body1: body1, body1: body2});
            //or defer.reject()
            console.log('SECOND:', body2); //returning 401
        });
    });
  
    return defer.promise;
  };
  
  var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
  flow.execute(createSession);
  flow.execute(function(){
    console.log("All requests were resolved");
  })
  
});
```